# Unicode version for python and debian 9

Tags: python, unicode, debian, version

For unicode version in my debian9

```
ls   /usr/share/doc/unicode-data
changelog.Debian.gz  copyright
```

Extract changelog.Debian.gz,some version info such as below:

```
unicode-data (9.0-1) unstable; urgency=medium

  * New upstream release. Closes: #827098.
  * Move to Standards-Version: 3.9.6. No changes required.

 -- Alastair McKinstry <mckinstry@debian.org>  Wed, 22 Jun 2016 14:49:26 +0100

unicode-data (8.0-3) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Fetch new allkeys.txt for Unicode 8. Closes: #809188.
  * Move to S-V: 3.9.6. No changes required.
  * Fix sort error in NameAliases.txt. Closes: #808465.

 -- Alastair McKinstry <mckinstry@debian.org>  Tue, 29 Dec 2015 02:15:32 +0000
```

The unicode version for my debian9 is 9.0-1 ?

For unicode version in python3

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.unidata_version
'8.0.0'
```

Does it mean that unicode version in my debian9 is 9.0-1 ,different from unicode version in my python3?

Comment: The files are just data. The visualization of glyph is done by font, and do no matter such files. Unicode, programs (so also your vim), etc. can handle undefined characters without problems.

Answer (score 4):

Python doesn't use system `unicodedata`. It is compiled an existing set. If you check the below url

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unicodedata.html

> This module provides access to the Unicode Character Database (UCD) which defines character properties for all Unicode characters. The data contained in this database is compiled from the UCD version 8.0.0.

and for `Python 3.6.5`

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unicodedata.html

> This module provides access to the Unicode Character Database (UCD) which defines character properties for all Unicode characters. The data contained in this database is compiled from the UCD version 9.0.0.

So its just that your system python version is not on `3.6.X` and that is why you see a `8.0.0`

Comment: I don't think VIM directly uses this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/470273/how-to-view-utf-8-unicode-characters-in-vim, it uses system locale/encoding. Now not sure if that in turn refers to this unicode data or not

Answer (score 2):

Python comes with built-in support for `unicodedata`.

e.g. my `/usr/share/doc/python3.6/changelog.gz` (running Debian/sid, so `Python3.6.5-3`) says:

> What's New in Python 3.6.0 beta 2?
>   [...]
>   - Upgrade internal unicode databases to Unicode version 9.0.0.

So it most likely ignores whatever you have installed on the system (e.g. via `unicode-data`).